# ¿Porque ucwords() se comporta como ucfirst()?

Tags: php

Tengo un arreglo de personas de las cuales quiero que la primera letra de cada palabra se convierta en capital, por lo tanto estoy utilizando `ucwords()`. El problema surge ya que está actuando como si estuviera utilizando `ucfirst()`.

Código:

```
foreach ($data['alumnos'] as &$alumno) {
  var_dump($alumno['nombre_completo']);
  $alumno['nombre_completo'] = ucwords(strtolower($alumno['nombre_completo']));
  var_dump($alumno['nombre_completo']);
}
```

Salida:

```
string(29) "BARRIOS HERNANDEZ CHRISTIAN"
string(29) "Barrios hernandez christian"
string(32) "CASTAÑEDA PADILLA JUAN DIEGO"
string(32) "CastaÑeda padilla juan diego"
string(31) "CORONA VALADEZ CARLOS ALEXIS"
string(31) "Corona valadez carlos alexis"
string(31) "DE REZA VELEZ JESUS OSWALDO"
string(31) "De reza velez jesus oswaldo"
string(34) "ALTAMIRANO MORELOS DAN EMMANUEL"
string(34) "Altamirano morelos dan emmanuel"
string(34) "ALVARADO CONTRERAS JORGE CARLOS"
string(34) "Alvarado contreras jorge carlos"
```

Solo convierte la primera letra como si fuese `ucfirst()`. En que parte lo estoy implementando de manera errónea o donde surge el problema.

Me funciona correctamente cuando lo hago de manera directa en un arreglo de una sola persona.

Ejemplo:

```
$data['profesor']['nombre_completo'] = ucwords(strtolower($data['profesor']['nombre_completo']));
```

Comment: En la BD estan en mayúsculas?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav así es, vienen en mayúsculas por eso muestro el primer var_dump, seguido las convierto a minúsculas para posteriormente utilizar el ucwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estaba probando tu código y solo cambie el `ucwords` por `mb_convert_case`, ya que este último tambien te transforma de una vez las letras con acento y tildes a minúsculas como la **Ñ**; puedes ver tu ejemplo corriendo [aquí](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn$data['alumnos']%20=%20array(array(%22nombre_completo%22%20=%3E%20%22BARRIOS%20HERNANDEZ%20CHRISTIAN%22),%20array(%22nombre_completo%22%20=%3E%20%22CASTA%C3%91EDA%20PADILLA%20JUAN%20DIEGO%22),%20array(%22nombre_completo%22%20=%3E%20%22CORONA%20VALADEZ%20CARLOS%20ALEXIS%22));%5Cn%5Cnforeach%20($data['alumnos']%20as%20$alumno)%20%7B%5Cn%20$nombre_completo2%20=%20mb_convert_case($alumno['nombre_completo'],%20MB_CASE_TITLE,%20%22UTF-8%22);%5Cn%20var_dump($nombre_completo2);%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn) con **mb_convert_case**, espero que sea lo que andas buscando.

**Ejemplo del mb_convert_case:**

```
<?php
  $str = "mary had a Little lamb and she loved it so";
  $str = mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
  echo $str; // Muestra MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB AND SHE LOVED IT SO
  $str = mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
  echo $str; // Muestra Mary Had A Little Lamb And She Loved It So
?>
```

El **mb_convert_case** posee 3 parametros:

**1) str:** El string que se va a convertir.

**2) mode:** El modo de conversión. Puede ser MB_CASE_UPPER, MB_CASE_LOWER, o MB_CASE_TITLE.

**3) encoding:** El parámetro encoding es la codificación de caracteres. Si es omitido, será usado el valor de la codificación de caracteres interna.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, no había utilizado mb_convert_case. Te debo una!